# HTML page should fix all the android device

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview

I have tried the following code to fit the webpage based on the device screen size.

```
    WebView mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test/index.html");
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

In this Zoomcontrols is working fine.
But webpage is not fixed to the device screen size.
Can anyone give me suggestions...?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following meta tag to your HTML file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I added, But webpage height and width is not fixed.